# How do you say “remember what angers you” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Was thinking this could be a sort of motto, similar to "memento mori". Perhaps it would fall along the lines of "memento [that which angers you]".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go with the famous *Memento…*, then I would suggest:

> Memento irritantium.

The verb [*meminisse*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmemini) (to remember) can be constructed in several ways, with the accusative or genetive, or with *de* + ablative. I chose the genetive in this case.

The noun is *irritans*, present participle of [*irritare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dirrito1) which does not just mean “irritate,” but in fact to provoke, enrage, stir up, exasperate, etc. *Irritiantium* is the genetive plural, i.e. “the things that are angering.” But note that (unlike English “that which”) it could also refer to the persons that are angering you.

Comment: Very nice and succinct. I'd recomment put a *te* in there as the direct object of *irritans*, although Latin often enough leaves out such an obvious object.